# Why do my new sunglasses make my iPhone and iPad look funny?

Tags: screen, display

Ok, I know... it's the polarization. And as the company just [tweeted at me](https://twitter.com/WarbyParkerHelp/status/323169622645952514):

> "Sorry about that! The polarization will protect your eyes though!"

This effect does not affect all Apple products (I get no weird glossy sheen on my Macbook Retina while wearing these sunglasses).

So which products does this affect? And is there anything I can do to mitigate the effect, such as affix a glare filter?

Answer (score 2):

It seems it's not EVERY phone or iPad - have you tried taking our device to the Apple Store and asking them?  (Yeah, I know, it's not always convenient and if you do, make sure you make a Genius Bar appointment ahead of time so you don't have to wait).

Take a look at this page:
http://www.phonearena.com/news/iPads-and-polarized-sunglasses-dont-mix_id28909

I can't seem to find why the problem occurs - it seems to be something about polarization needs to be at 45 degrees:
[Why are LCD Panels Polarized at 45 degrees](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/28113/why-are-lcd-panels-polarized-at-45-degrees)

Comment: When I wear my polarized sunglasses I'm getting slightly different images in my left & right eyes. My iPhone is darker in my left eye.  If I rotate the phone through 360 degrees it is at its darkest when upright (in both eyes), just noticeably darker in the left eye.  Is this normal?

Answer (score 0):

You have Polarized lenses. Nothing to worry about.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would you be willing to elaborate a little? The OP mentioned he would like to mitigate the effects if possible, as well as learn which devices amplify this problem.